# Missing '='. in Debian service

Tags: linux, debian, system, daemon

I've created this service in /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service

in a

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
```

This is the content:

```
[Unit]
Description=webapp daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start-webapp.sh
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/stop-webapp.sh
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/reload-webapp.sh
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=webapp.service
```

I try to startd the service using:

```
sudo systemctl start webapp.service
```

But when I do

```
sudo systemctl status webapp.service
```

I got this error:

```
● webapp.service - webapp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webapp.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jun 01 11:31:48 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service:8: Missing '='.
Jun 01 11:31:52 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service:8: Missing '='.
Jun 01 11:35:21 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service:8: Missing '='.
Jun 01 11:35:31 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service:8: Missing '='.
```

and

```
   admin@localhost:/etc/systemd/system$ cat -vetn webapp.service 
         1  [Unit]$
         2  Description=webapp daemon$
         3  [Service]$
         4  Type=simple$
         5  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start-webapp.sh$
         6  ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/stop-webapp.sh$
         7  ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/reload-webapp.sh$
         8  [Install]$
         9  WantedBy=multi-user.target$
```

Comment: A few things you can try: 1. Remove all the spaces around the equal signs. 2. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: Multiply posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/590413/5132 .

Comment: Can you try "sudo systemctl daemon-reload"? and then restarting the service.

Comment: Your service's unit file looks alright from the `cat` output. Run `sudo systemctl reload-or-restart webapp.service` and share if you still get the same error.

Comment: Is service file UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: yes, it is UTF-8 encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config content seems nothing wrong, so I have copied it to my debian server and try to run it, and it's really ok.

But it's strange that the stdout of `cat -vetn webapp.service` is not the exactly content of your original config, so would you mind to remove the original config and do it again ?

refer: https://wiki.debian.org/systemd/Services

1. redo:

   `mv webapp.service /tmp/webapp.service
   vi webapp.service #  check characters`
2. After creating or modifying any unit files, we must tell systemd that we want it to look for new things:

   `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Then, tell systemd to enable it, so that it will start every time we boot:

   `systemctl enable myservice.service`
4. Finally, start it:

   `systemctl start myservice.service`

Comment: I had the same problem. It was a trailing empty line at the end of the .service file.

Comment: In my case it was a trailing ~ in the end of the file. But, did not notice it in vim